# SSRS 2016 automation using Management webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I am doing some automation with SQL 2016 Reporting Services by accessing its Management web service.

Here is my code:

```
private Policy[] GetItemPolicy(string itemPath = "/", Boolean InheritParent = true)
    {
        ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        rs.Url = url;
        try
        {
            return rs.GetPolicies(itemPath, out InheritParent);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log(ex.Message);
        }
        return rs.GetPolicies(itemPath, out InheritParent);
    }
```

The ex.Message is The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden

I have added a machine account where it's running to Report Portal. 
Any idea what my problem might be?

Both my code (IIS) and SSRS SQL Server are running on the same box.

While I was developing this solution I was using a distributed architecture where application server and SSRS server were on different machines.

It worked fine there. Is there any restriction using the same approach on a single machine?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are using the web service url and not the report manager url?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, how could I miss it ... Thank you!